# How to prove that most of the systems of PDEs cannot be decoupled?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let's consider the following system
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}
u\\v
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
f(x,t,u,v,u_x,v_x)\\g(x,t,u,v,u_x,v_x)
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
If there locally exists a invertible mapping, s.t. the system in new coordinates becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\tilde{t}}\begin{pmatrix}
 \tilde{u}\\\tilde{v}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
 \tilde{f}(\tilde{x},\tilde{t},\tilde{u},\tilde{v},\tilde{u}_{\tilde{x}},\tilde{v}_{\tilde{x}})\\
 \tilde{g}(\tilde{x},\tilde{t},\tilde{v},\tilde{v}_{\tilde{x}})
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
we call the original system can be decoupled.

Intuitively, most of systems aren't decoupled, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Do you really mean to allow the derivative of $\tilde u$ to depend on $\tilde v$?

Comment: Also, before you can hope to prove your statement, you need to define it:  what does 'most' mean?